# Sci-fi book about mercenaries who sell advanced weaponry on various planets

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm trying to find the name of a sci-fi book I read in the 80's. It's about some mercenaries who go to planets and sell advanced weaponry to warring parties. They arrive on a planet of masters and slaves. The masters eat the slaves babies as a rite of passage and have sharpened teeth.

Comment: I'm gonna make a wild guess here.  Could it possibly be "The Men in the Jungle" by Norman Spinrad?  My guess is based on cannibalism and you saying it was "ages ago".  https://www.amazon.com/Men-Jungle-Norman-Spinrad/dp/1490446052

Answer (score 7):

#### ["*The Men in the Jungle*"](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/633190.The_Men_in_the_Jungle) by Norman Spinrad.

> All his life, Fraden had been in control, had bent situations, conditions, people, to his own will. He had stood solidly, reaching out to change men and events, but had never been changed by them. He had been booted out of Greater New York, he had taken and lost the Asteroid Belt, and he was still the same Bart Fraden. But on Sangre... something had been done to him. He had been tampered with. For the first time in his life, Bart Fraden felt himself moved by forces beyond his conscious control. Had he changed Sangre? Or had the planet changed him? For the first time in his life, Bart Fraden was afraid.
>
> <sub>[Amazon, *The Men in the Jungle*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1490446052)</sub>

---

Credit to [Emsley Wyatt](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/191046/sci-fi-book-about-mercenaries-who-sell-advanced-weaponry-on-various-planets/191073#comment521445_191046) for finding the answer.

Comment: Note that you should be able to accept your own answer after 48 hours of asking the question so in ~40 hours. Please do so!

Comment: I didn't want to make my guess an actual answer as I no longer have the book to check details.  The original question could have covered that book, or other books that I'm not even aware of.  But since it was it, glad to help.